# Checkbox doesn't take using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Boolean field called `:active` and is changeable via Ajax. I have it working for unchecking the box, thereby making the boolean FALSE, or moreover, in the database it removes the attribute making it empty, but works nonetheless.

My problem is it does not work in reverse. I can check the box to make the boolean TRUE and it appears that it is doing something, but it does not actually make a change in the database.

The output in Webbrick shows it updated:

```
Processing by CompaniesController#toggle as JS
Parameters:  {"Active"=>"228", "id"=>"228"}
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "companies" SET "active" = $1, "updated_at" = $2
             WHERE "companies"."id" = $3 [["active", nil], 
             ["updated_at", 2017-02-15 17:26:19 UTC], ["id", 228]]
(0.8ms)      COMMIT
```

But the database didn’t update. I see where it says `[[“active, nil]` above, and that is the part that is not right. So technically the update is working, but I’m pretty sure my controller is why it is sending a `nil` on recheck.

So, how do I send a boolean `TRUE` in my controller, if that is indeed where I should do it.

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def toggle
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  if @company.update_attributes(active: params[:active])
    # todo: maybe give a notice
  else
    # todo: maybe give a notice
  end
end
```

**index.html.rb**

```
<%= check_box_tag 'Active', company.id, company.active,
      data: {
        remote: true,
        url: url_for(action: :toggle, id: company.id),
        method: "POST"
      } %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :companies do
  resources :comments
  member do
    post 'toggle'
  end
end
```

---

## Edit

I got it to work by changing my controller to use an if statement. Not sure if this is the best approach, but it does work in both directions now.

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def toggle
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  if @company.active
    @company.update_attributes(active: FALSE)
  else
    @company.update_attributes(active: TRUE)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you just want to fix your existing code than the error is that you are using `company.id` as the value for the check box - not the boolean column.

Comment: I saw that, eventually, where `(active: params[:active])` is giving the `id` instead of a boolean. Your answer (below) adds jQuery but removes messing with the routes. I'll try that way out as well.

Comment: If you are using rails_ujs you are already have jQuery as a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need a separate route. Rather you can just send a PATCH request to your existing route:

```
<% form_for(@company) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :active, class: "company-toggle-active" %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure the controller handles JSON:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    if @company.update(company_attributes)
      respond_to do |f|
        f.json { head :ok }
        f.html { redirect_to @company }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |f|
        f.json { json: { errors: @company.errors }, status: 422 }
        f.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private 
  def company_attributes
    params.require(:company).permit(:foo, :bar, :active)
  end
end
```

We can then setup an handler for the change event that updates with ajax:

```
$(document).on('change', '.company-toggle-active', function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: this.form.action,
    type: 'PATCH',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      company: {
        active: $(this).is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false' 
      }
    }
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // do something if request is successful
  }).fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // do something if request fails
  });
});
```